ffmpeg to make switchable audio and subtitles on black video
I want to use ffmpeg to make a blank (black) video with audio and subtitles in different languages. I was able to (1) make a black video, (2) add 3 audio tracks to it, but I failed to (3) add subtitles to it. No subtitles appear even though all 3 audio are there and switchable.
(1) I made the black (silent) video using:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i black.jpg -i silent.mp3 -acodec copy -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 silent.mov

where black.jpg is a 1280x720 black image and silent.mp3 has 5 min of silence
(2) I added the 3 audio tracks (talian, french, german) using:
ffmpeg -i silent.mov -i ita.mp3 -i fre.mp3 -i ger.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -map 3:a -metadata:s:a:0 language=ita -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra -metadata:s:a:2 language=ger ita-fre-ger.mov

(3) I tried to add subtitles for each language using:
ffmpeg -i ita-fre-ger.mov -i ita.srt -i fre.srt -i ger.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=ita -metadata:s:s:1 language=fra -metadata:s:s:2 language=ger final.mov

Just this last command didn't work. How do I get the subtitles to add? I'd be happy to use .mp4 instead of .mov, but it didn't work either.
Update: Thanks to @Ricardo Bohner gave the answer. For completeness, here is how I applied it and it worked great:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=black:s=1280x720" -i ita.srt -i fre.srt -i ger.srt -i ita.mp3 -i fre.mp3 -i ger.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:s:0 -map 2:s:0 -map 3:s:0 -map 4:a -map 5:a -map 6:a -metadata:s:a:0 language=ita -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra -metadata:s:a:2 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 language=ita -metadata:s:s:1 language=fra -metadata:s:s:2 language=ger -c:s:0 mov_text -c:s:1 mov_text -c:s:2 mov_text -shortest test.mp4


What error do you get in step 3?

I get no error -- the video simply has no subtitles added.

For me this worked for mp4
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=black:s=1280x720" -i ita.mp3 -i fre.mp3 -i ger.mp3 -i ita.srt -i fre.srt -i ger.srt -map 0:v -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0 -map 3:a:0 -map 4:s:0 -map 5:s:0 -map 6:s:0 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ita -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra -metadata:s:a:2 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 language=ita -metadata:s:s:1 language=fra -metadata:s:s:2 language=ger -c:s:0 mov_text -c:s:1 mov_text -c:s:2 mov_text -shortest test.mp4

When I try to create this same file as *.mov file I get the following error:
FATAL error, file duration too long for timebase, this file will not be 7.9kbits/s speed=21.1x
playable with QuickTime. Choose a different timebase with -video_track_timescale or a different container format
But the mov file still plays as expected in VLC player

Please see updated answer.

Apparently I figured it out at the same time you were updating your answer. I put things in a different order but apparently that doesn't matter -- much thanks!
